# Mopub: Testing Facebook Audience Network Native Ad integration

Tags: android, mopub, facebook-audience-network

I'm unsure how one can test Facebook Audience Network integration with Mopub. On the Facebook Audience Network page on testing, it doesn't reveal any information on testing integration with Native ads :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing

In the mopub docs, I have completed all the steps for integration with a Third Party Ad Network:

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Native-Third-Party-Ad-Networks

I have also completed this part of the tutorial on self-testing your creatives by creating an inventory item which is a native ad and an test order that serves the native ad. This works successfully for my app but this is a my very own **created** ad, it is not a **facebook ad**:

https://dev.twitter.com/mopub-demand/overview/self-testing-your-creatives

**INVENTORY SCREEN**:
It shows the ad source breakdown and this does not include Facebook Audience Network.

[image]

**ORDER SCREEN**

The screen shows my very own created order which works with my app. I can see my own creative within my app:

[image]

**NETWORK SCREEN**

This is the network screen showing that I have added FacebookAudienceNetwork:

[image]

This is the configuration for the FacebookAudienceNetwork:

[image]

The Facebook placement_id is darken out in the picture below, but it matches with the one on facebook.

**Facebook website**:

[image]

How do I know that Facebook Audience Network has been integrated successfully with MoPub for native ads - is there a way to test this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally solved this through a response from MoPub from their support staff. The below is the email I was sent. Hopefully, this will also help someone else with their integration:

> Thanks for reaching out!  When you tested your integration were you
>   able to see the MoPub test creative for your native ad unit?  If so,
>   that means your initial MoPub integration is correct.
>
> Next, you'll want to target FAN against your ad units.  To do this
>   please follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to the "Segments" tab in the MoPub UI
> 2. Click the specified segment you want to set (Note: Accounts will automatically be set with a Global Segment on creation. This would be
>      the segment most people would need to navigate to to set the ad
>      network for the specific ad unit. This changes if a new segment is
>      created and has specific targeting as new segments will override the
>      Global Segment for their specific parameters.)
> 3. There is a filter set to show only running ad sources. You want to close the tab for this that says "Status:Running" inside the filter
>      box to see the rest of the ad sources.
> 4. Click the drop down for the ad unit you want to change
> 5. Edit the ecpm of the ad source
> 6. Click "Set"
>
> After Facebook is enabled on your ad unit, you can start testing live
>   Facebook ads.  You will want to make sure you have the Facebook app
>   installed on your device with a Facebook account set up against it in
>   order to see ads.  Additionally, you will want to make sure you are
>   using the MoPub certified version of the FAN SDK, which is 4.8.1 for
>   Android.
>
> If you aren't seeing any Facebook ads after you complete these testing
>   steps please let us know.  Be sure to include device logs in your
>   response so we an get a better idea of what is going on when you try
>   to call FAN ads.

Just to clarify as well in the docs MoPub refers that you need to put the extra adapters inside your `'src'` folder in your android app. I found that by doing this, I ended up getting a log message saying that `FacebookNative.java` file is not found.
You will need to add the extra adapters into your main -> java folder for android to detect them.

Comment: "you will want to make sure you are using the MoPub certified version of the FAN SDK, which is 4.8.1 for Android." I can't emphasize more the importance of this statement. Use ONLY version 4.8.1, using anything newer will cause impression not being tracked. I've been pulling my hair for weeks because of this.

Comment: This saved me possibly a lot of time debugging.. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I am still unable to get ads. Can you please share source code of implementing native ads.

Comment: @Simon I am still unable to get ads, it' shows me request in mopub and facebook console.... can you please help me? I am adding my logs here...

ProxyCache: Proxy cache server started. Ping it...
ProxyCache: Open connection  to http://127.0.0.1:60377/ping
MoPub: Native Ad failed to load with error: Third-party network failed to provide an ad..
MoPub: Native ad request failed.
 com.mopub.network.MoPubNetworkError: No ads found for ad unit.
           at com.mopub.network.AdRequest.parseNetworkResponse(AdRequest.java:142)